# Get all strings from array in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a beginner in node and mongoDb. I send a models from the application to node.

```
const { users } = req.body;

console.log(users);
```

and when I print this I have this result.

```
[
  '{"id":"6389f4206f784a8e3d75cf10","email":"test5@test.com","password":"$2a$08$2cE5XFlShV0nBYS6JF4ckuRLcEvp75YuCazQLSyIZ6bKu5kev/dwS","verify":1,"invitationsToMe":["6390a3b8cb716fa4d67d82d6"],"invitationsFromMe":[],"friendsList":["638777339b32b61a57e5ab4b","638889b46b30846785db55df","638776e89b32b61a57e5ab43","638797306307ba909c43be22"],"username":"Przemek"}',
  '{"id":"638797306307ba909c43be22","email":"test3@test.com","password":"$2a$08$wvtwkdwzKg.ZbEvWb2L5desAwoX0gUj723V/WgqiRRRFGl4AEltrm","verify":1,"invitationsToMe":["6390a3b8cb716fa4d67d82d6"],"invitationsFromMe":[],"friendsList":["638777339b32b61a57e5ab4b","638776e89b32b61a57e5ab43","638889b46b30846785db55df","6389f4206f784a8e3d75cf10"],"username":"Maciek"}',
  '{"id":"638777339b32b61a57e5ab4b","email":"test2@test.com","password":"$2a$08$Zl8eJP8B2yYJaFMdH5045uQZnKB8JMmOMmMfCQXN/C0UfN1eMWdAi","verify":1,"invitationsToMe":["6390a3b8cb716fa4d67d82d6"],"invitationsFromMe":[],"friendsList":["638797306307ba909c43be22","638776e89b32b61a57e5ab43","638889b46b30846785db55df","6389f4206f784a8e3d75cf10"],"username":"Bartolinio"}'
]
```

Now i want to extract from each "id" number to save in array in mondoDb. I found only .find( with filters ) but it not working for me.

Comment: you need to convert this array of string, to array of json(js objects here) and then use [insert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) (see the nodejs insert method) so they can saved in mongodb.

Comment: Yes I forgot about convert to json. Thanks for insert method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const strings = [
  '{"id":"6389f4206f784a8e3d75cf10","email":"test5@test.com","password":"$2a$08$2cE5XFlShV0nBYS6JF4ckuRLcEvp75YuCazQLSyIZ6bKu5kev/dwS","verify":1,"invitationsToMe":["6390a3b8cb716fa4d67d82d6"],"invitationsFromMe":[],"friendsList":["638777339b32b61a57e5ab4b","638889b46b30846785db55df","638776e89b32b61a57e5ab43","638797306307ba909c43be22"],"username":"Przemek"}',
  '{"id":"638797306307ba909c43be22","email":"test3@test.com","password":"$2a$08$wvtwkdwzKg.ZbEvWb2L5desAwoX0gUj723V/WgqiRRRFGl4AEltrm","verify":1,"invitationsToMe":["6390a3b8cb716fa4d67d82d6"],"invitationsFromMe":[],"friendsList":["638777339b32b61a57e5ab4b","638776e89b32b61a57e5ab43","638889b46b30846785db55df","6389f4206f784a8e3d75cf10"],"username":"Maciek"}',
  '{"id":"638777339b32b61a57e5ab4b","email":"test2@test.com","password":"$2a$08$Zl8eJP8B2yYJaFMdH5045uQZnKB8JMmOMmMfCQXN/C0UfN1eMWdAi","verify":1,"invitationsToMe":["6390a3b8cb716fa4d67d82d6"],"invitationsFromMe":[],"friendsList":["638797306307ba909c43be22","638776e89b32b61a57e5ab43","638889b46b30846785db55df","6389f4206f784a8e3d75cf10"],"username":"Bartolinio"}'
]

const objects = strings.map(str => JSON.parse(str))

console.log(objects)
```